People condemned to appear in photos throughout recorded history
What I remember about the plot is:
The movie is about a group of people who were condemned [by god?] because they did something wrong, and they were forced to appear in photos throughout recorded history (same faces appear in all shown photos) proving that they are subjected to tragedies and misfortune as punishment for what they did.
It was in English, it was a color movie, I have seen it around 15 years ago, but it might have been made before that.
Can you identify this movie by plot?

Was it  black&white or color? When did you watched it?

I have a couple of vague ideas, but more details (like the country\language, genre and approximate year of release) might help.

Language: English, it was a colored movie, I have seen it around 15 years ago, but it might have been made before that. What are your guesses? @Walt

Language: English, it was a colored movie, I have seen it around 15 years ago, but it might have been made before that. @mattiav27

Could it have been slightly less than 15 years ago?

@Walt yes it could have been less that 15 years. I am not sure anymore.

Sounds a lot like The Gathering with Christina Ricci. It's from 2003, which might be close enough.

While going to the town of Ashby Wake, the drifter Cassie is hit by a car driven by Marion Kirkman and loses her memory. Marion invites Cassie to stay in her huge old house with her family, while recovering from the trauma. [...] Her findings about who she is and the mystery relative to the locals and the town surprises her.

It's revealed that the town's people are immortal and condemned to witness tragedies throughout history after witnessing the crucifixion of Christ (and appear in many drawings and photos). IIRC, they also started causing these tragedies at some point. Here's the trailer:




OK, thanks. It also reminded me of a segment in the Twilight Zone movie, a couple of movies where time-travellers seek out famous tragedies, and a certain pivotal scene in 12 Monkeys.
